# Three dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to create three dropdown selections of names using php, javascript and jquery and get the data from mysql. So if I select a certain name on the first selection then it wont show on other selections and same goes to other selections as well. can you help me please ?

Comment: Why, where are you stuck? See also [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question. You need to ask about a specific problem, if you ask vaguely for "help" on a whole feature then we have no idea what you need, and we're not going to write the whole thing for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, you mean like (country, city) dropdowns.
So when you choose a different country, the list of cities changes.

If that's what you mean, then here is the solution:

You add an "onchange" listener to the first select.
And on change you change the innerHTML of the second select.

**Method 1:**

To get your data from PHP you can print it in the script with echo. So instead of "My Option 1" you print your data.

```html
<select onchange="changeSelection(this)">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>

<select id="select-2"></select>

<script>
function changeSelection(selectTag){
// to get your data from php you can print the values you want with echo
  if(selectTag.value == "option1"){
    document.getElementById("select-2").innerHTML = "<option value='my-option1'>My Option1</option>"
  }else if(selectTag.value == "option2"){
    document.getElementById("select-2").innerHTML = "<option value='my-option2'>My Option2</option>"
  }
  // And you continue with all the options you have, and the same thing with the third select tag
}
</script>
```

**Method 2:**

Or you can use ajax queries to get your data on each change.

this code should be in the function triggered by onchange listener:

```
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "yourPHPfile.php", true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        let data = xhr.response;
        document.getElementById("select-2").innerHTML = data;
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send("selectValue=" + selectValue);
```

Where the file "yourPHPfile.php" should return the values you want in the second selector, according to the value you send it in $_POST["selectValue"].